# mrtg errors after upgrading to Debian Squeeze

Tags: ipv6, debian-squeeze

Since upgrading from Debian Lenny to Squeeze, I've had the following problem with `mrtg`:

```
root@turtle:~# env LANG=C /usr/bin/mrtg
Constant subroutine SNMP_Session::AF_INET6 redefined at /usr/share/perl/5.10/Exporter.pm line 67 at /usr/share/perl5/SNMP_Session.pm line 149
Prototype mismatch: sub SNMP_Session::AF_INET6 () vs none at /usr/share/perl/5.10/Exporter.pm line 67 at /usr/share/perl5/SNMP_Session.pm line 149
Constant subroutine SNMPv1_Session::AF_INET6 redefined at /usr/share/perl/5.10/Exporter.pm line 67 at /usr/share/perl5/SNMP_Session.pm line 608
Prototype mismatch: sub SNMPv1_Session::PF_INET6 () vs none at /usr/share/perl/5.10/Exporter.pm line 67 at /usr/share/perl5/SNMP_Session.pm line 608
```

To clarify, I have `mrtg 2.16.3-3`, `Perl 5.10.1` and `libsnmp-session-perl is 1.13-1`.

There seems to be a [similar bug in Gentoo Linux](http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=321701), but I don't really understand the resolution to that and whether there's something wrong with my system.

I tried going to the [Debian `mrtg` package page](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/mrtg) and looking at the bug reports but it only seems to list bugs for unstable (`sid`).

Anyone able to talk me through how to fix this?

**Edit:** For the record I also already have the `libsocket6-perl 0.23-1` package. Earlier version of question also had reference to missing `eaccelerator` module - since fixed (due to having a symlink in the PHP5 cli directory to the same `conf.d` as used by the apache version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in libsnmp-session-perl, the Debian bug report is at http://bugs.debian.org/628804 (it has links to other pages about it).

You could try the patch given at http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg-trac/ticket/45 if the problem is actually stopping things working (if it's just producing log noise you may prefer to put up with it for the time being). The cost would be keeping your modified libsnmp-session-perl up to date in the face of any updates Debian may apply to it.

Comment: Thanks - what I did was add MAILTO='' to the particular cron file to suppress the notifications every 5 minutes.  The graphs are still fine..